# Smooth functions

Tags: differential-geometry

I look at the following exercise of A. Pressley:

Show that the Gaussian and mean curvatures of a surface S are smooth functions on $S$.

$$$$

Is it so?

We consider a smooth $\sigma$.

The formula of the Gaussian curvature is $$K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}$$ and the formula of the mean curvature is $$H=\frac{LG-2MF+NE}{2(EG-F^2)}$$

$E=\|\sigma_u \|^2 , \ F=\sigma_u \cdot \sigma_v, \ G=\|\sigma_v\|^2, \ L=\sigma_{uu}\cdot \textbf{N}, \ M=\sigma_{uv}\cdot \textbf{N}, \ N=\sigma_{vv}\cdot \textbf{N}, \ \textbf{N}=\frac{\sigma_u \times \sigma_v}{\|\sigma_u \times \sigma_v\|}$.

Each of these terms is smooth, or?

Then also $LN-M^2$, $LG-2MF+NE$ and $EG-F^2$ are smooth, or?

$$$$

Edit:

We consider that $S$ is smooth, so also its parametrization $\sigma$.

Having that $\sigma$ is smooth, its partial derivatives of all orders are continuous.

So $$ E=\|\sigma_u\|^2, \ F=\sigma_u \cdot \sigma_v, \ G=\|\sigma_v\|^2, \ L=\sigma_{uu}\cdot \mathbf{N}, \ M=\sigma_{uv}\cdot \mathbf{N}, \\ N=\sigma_{vv}\cdot \mathbf{N}, \ \mathbf{N}=\frac{\sigma_u \times \sigma_v}{\|\sigma_u \times \sigma_v\|}$$ are smooth functions.

Then the Gauss curvature $K=\frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F^2}$ and the mean curvature $H=\frac{LG-2MF+NE}{2(EG-F^2)}$ are smooth functions.

Is the justification correct and enough?

Comment: You might ask yourself what it means for $\sigma$ to be smooth.

Comment: $\sigma$ is smooth if all its components are smooth, i.e., continuous. Correct? @TedShifrin

Comment: Your i.e. Is not right. In math it is essential to look up and learn the definitions!

Comment: It must be, each of the components have continuous derivatives. Or not? @TedShifrin

Comment: Which derivatives?

Comment: partial derivatives @TedShifrin

Comment: Tell me the exact definition in the book.

Comment: If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, we say that a map $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth if each of the $n$ components of $f$, which are functions $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, have continuous
partial derivatives of all orders. @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes, continuous partial derivatives of all orders. So now answer your questions ....

Comment: All the partial derivatives of all orders are continuous. The dot product and Cross product of two smooth curves is also smooth. Or not? @TedShifrin